# Qt - how to use the same delegate for different views in a stacked widget

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, tableview

Ok, so I am creating an app that includes a stacked widget that has two pages with two different views that display different information.  Both views require different delegates for individual columns, For example the first two columns use line edits, the next two use spin boxes, etc.  However both views hold different information and manipulate and store them in different ways, and I do this by setModelData method from within the delegate.

I can't use the exact same code in the setModelData method for both views because the data is not stored the same, so is there a way to be able to tell within the delegate what page the stackedWidget is on so I can use control statements to choose what to do with the data?  Or I am stuck with having to create all new delegates for each view?

Comment: You might mark the delegate somehow with a flag that will tell which view the delegate is set to. However this will force you to write if-else blocks in each virtual functions you override. The most preferable approach is having a custom delegate per view type. This will make your code much clearer and less coupled.

Comment: Your delegate should have no idea of what view or model it's acting on. its job is to paint a single item, create an editor for the item and return the edited data. introducing a condition based on view (or even column index for that matter) is a flaw in the design

Comment: @vahancho the way I have set up this project so far uses different types of editors (e.g. line edits and spin boxes) for the same view dependent on the column.  I went about doing this by creating a different delegate for the different editors and then assigning those delegates to a model by column.  However, when I look at this in the big picture, I am going to have a total of 4 views in this project, meaning if I keep this approach I could end up with around 10 delegates which just seems messy.  Is this normal practice or is there a better way? I'm fairly new to Qt.

Comment: @stor314, I would go in the direction when there are a delegate per model (not view). I would create even a class hierarchy for my delegates to share some common code, if any. You don't need a delegate per column. You should handle different columns inside of delegate's virtual functions like: `if (index.column() == 0) {}...` etc.